¿Cómo puedo ordenar un array en JavaScript?
Estoy trabajando en JavaScript y necesito ordenar un array de números.
He intentado usar array.sort(), pero me gustaría entender cómo funciona y asegurarme de estar haciendo uso del metodo correctamente.
Agradezco cualquier ejemplo de código o consejo sobre cómo puedo ordenar un array de manera eficiente y efectiva en JavaScript.
¿Cuál es la mejor manera de hacerlo en JavaScript?
Este seria mi codigo:


const array = [3, 1, 5, 2, 4];
array.sort((a, b) => a - b);
console.log(array);




No entiendo tu pregunta. ¿Que problemas tienes con el código dado?, o como quieres ordenarlo??, ¿De menor a mayor como tu ejemplo?(como tu código) o de mayor a menor (array.sort(a,b)=> b-a;)?

a que te referis con la mejor manera... si esa lo ordena ya sirve.. no??? y si queres saber como funciona sort, nada mejor que la documentacion de sort

Como la mayoría de las veces, no hay una forma mejor ya que cada una tiene sus puntos a favor. ¿La mejor según qué criterio? La más conveniente por supuesto es utilizar la función sort que poseen los arreglos. ¿Cómo funciona? La documentación da a entender que la implementación puede variar así que no hay una sola respuesta correcta. Sin embargo, puedes crear una propia, más adecuada a tus necesidades.

@Francisco la complejidad es logarítmica. https://stackoverflow.com/a/57763259
